# Can't load PSModule from 'C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\MSOnline\1.1.183.57\PSModule\'. An attempt was made to load incorrect format

Tags: c#, powershell, office365

I don't know even after setting x86 and Any CPU configuration from configuration manager, why it is not loading the module from right context. I checked from PowerShell script `[Environment]::Is64bitProcess` as False. No idea why it is false even I set the target platform from configuration manager as 'x64' or Any  CPU or Mixed Platform. Nothing works.!!

[image]

and then I am getting following exception of loading module in incorrect format. Executing command was `Connect-MsolService`

[image]

In configuration Manager, following configurations are set.

[image]

Comment: I'm no C# coder really, but I assume you imported/linked/referenced (whatever it is called) the `System.Management.Automation.dll` at some point? Which one? Or maybe that's automagic these days...?

Comment: yes its already imported.

Comment: This has some steps,plz ignore if you had already went through this https://github.com/PowerShell/vscode-powershell/issues/1617

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all others, those  who are having the same problem, simply go to IIS server pool where the application is running. Go to the properties of applicaion pool and change 'Enable 32 bit application' value to 'False'.

[image]

Hope for rest everything is fine. No need to change the configuration at visual studio configuration if application is running under Local IIS. Otherwise, probably Configuration Manager settings for all assemblies including in the solution might work.